# Mathematica cannot generate the random variables for a given Probability Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

I need to generate a large number of random variables from the distribution generated by the following code. Distribution is given by `DistributionF`. The code is getting stuck at the the execution of the command `RandomVariate[DistributionF,1000]`. It does not output the R.V.s. How can I resolve this issue.

```
A = 1/2; 
k = 1; τ = 1;
m = 1; β = .6931; σ = 1.8421;


W = {0.0000, 0.0013, 0.0339, 0.2401, 0.6109, 0.6109, 0.2401, 0.0339, 
   0.0013, 0.0000};

T = {3.4362, 2.5327, 1.7567, 1.0366, 
   0.3429, -0.3429, -1.0366, -1.7567, -2.5327, -3.4362};

G[t_] := Exp[-Exp[-Sqrt[2]*σ*t - β]*m*
     x^2]*(Exp[Sqrt[2]*σ*t + β])^(-m);

f[x_] = (1 - A)*
    FullSimplify[
     2*(1 + k)*x/τ*Exp[-k - (1 + k)*x^2/τ]*
      BesselJ[0, 2*Sqrt[k*(1 + k)/τ]*x]] + 
   A*(x^(2*m - 1)*2*m^m)/(Sqrt[π]*Gamma[m])*W.(G /@ T);

DistributionF = TransformedDistribution[x^2, 
   x \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]];

RandomVariate[DistributionF,1000]
```

Comment: If `f[x]` is a PDF then `NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, ∞}]` should return `1` since you have defined `{0, ∞}` as the domain of `f`.  However, it returns `0.567652`.

Comment: @Edmund - The `Method` option can handle this. `ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "Normalize"]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Nice!  I did not notice that before. Still taking forever to evaluate for just 1 sample.

Comment: Works for me, 10.x on Windows...

Comment: @ciao, I have been using 11.01 on Mac..